# How to queue TFS build using a custom branch with c# nuget package?

Tags: c#, git, tfs, build

Im trying to queue a build for specific branches after determining if that branch has tests running on it.  I have to be able to to tell TFS which branch to build though, because the default definition is just master.

I found this already: [TFS Build API by Exmaple](http://www.woodwardweb.com/dotnet/tfs_build_api_b.html), and it was somewhat helpful, until I found out it only queues the default build definitions.  We can use other build agents, but not specifiying which branch to build.

According to this picture: [Inheritance Chart for IBuildServer](http://www.woodwardweb.com/WindowsLiveWriter/TFSBuildAPIbyExample1Queueabuild_C1CE/BuildAPI_2.gif), there are multiple components at play here but after some looking for several hours I cant find anywhere that allows me to specify which branch I want to be built.

Please help, thanks so much in advance!

Edit 1: So I did a fiddler catch on the web request as I queue a build from the UI and it looks like I need to find where I can set the source branch attribute.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of TFS?

Comment: @Matt 2018 but I dont know which update within 2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest api for [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) and [TFS 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/build/builds?view=tfs-2018) documentation exposes a parameter called 'Source Branch' as part of the POST method.

You can generate your own API call or use [AzurePipelinesPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS). It is a PowerShell wrapper for the rest api.

Try the New-APBuild command, I added support for the source branch for in version 1.0.57.

Comment: Actually thanks so much, they also expose this parameter in the QueueBuildAsync method in c# that should do the trick as well! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2018, you have access to the REST API to [queue a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).  Part of the request allows you to specify the source branch.  I would leverage that instead.